# What am I missing setting up channel layers?

Tags: django, websocket, webhooks, django-channels

I followed the django channel tutorial

```
# channels
redis_host = os.environ.get('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost')
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [(redis_host, 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

in my code it gives me this error.
2020-01-10 00:29:22,045 ERROR    Exception inside application: [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('0.0.0.0', 6379)

Am I supposed to set up my server somewhere?
my procfile has this:

```
web: daphne APbackend.asgi:application --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0
```

Do I change the port 6379 to $PORT?

Answer (score 0):

turns out I need a redis server in my computer, and also on heroku.

always learning.